# Why MKMapView Has NSObject as property

Tags: xcode, mkmapview

I'm trying to understand the MKMapView class

Based on the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

One of the property of MKMapView is annotations.
But isn't the premise of MVC is that Views don't own the data?

In an example implementation of the class I've seen, the annotation property was actually declared in MapViewController.h that encompass the mapview object. So how's the annotation even a property of MapView.

Please point out if any of my assumption/understanding is wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> One of the property of MKMapView is annotations. But isn't the premise
>   of MVC is that Views don't own the data?

A view such as a map view shouldn't manage data -- that is, it shouldn't know or care where the data comes from, worry about saving it, etc. But in most cases it'd be hard for a view to know how to draw itself without knowing what data is supposed to be represented in the view. You couldn't expect a label to put the right characters on the screen unless you tell it what the label's text should be, right? It's the same with annotations. The map view doesn't know or care where they come from or what kind of class they are. As long as they implement the MKAnnotation protocol, the map view is happy. It has to retain any annotations that have been added to the map, of course, but it doesn't need to know anything else about them.

> In an example implementation of the class I've seen, the annotation
>   property was actually declared in MapViewController.h that encompass
>   the mapview object.

The map view controller often needs to know about the annotations as well. After all, it's usually the controller that manages the annotations and adds them to the map in the first place. Also, the view controller is usually the object that acts as the map view delegate, so it's the object that has to respond when someone taps the annotation's accessory.

> So how's the annotation even a property of MapView.

MKMapView takes care of displaying the right annotations for the geographic area displayed on the map. To do that, it needs to know *all* the annotations that *could* be displayed. You add annotations that you want the map to display when the associated area is visible, and you don't have to figure out which ones are visible every time the map area changes. In order to do that, the map obviously has to keep track of all the annotations that have been added.

It didn't have to be that way. MKMapView could have been implemented like UITableView; it could have asked a delegate for the data to display for a given area. Just as UITableViewDataSource has `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, MKMapDelegate could have had a `-mapView:annotationsForRegion:` method. But if it had been done that way, every map delegate would have had to be able to efficiently find the annotations for the given region and SO would have dozens of questions about how to properly implement a quad tree for the sake of providing the right set of annotations to the map view. Putting all that logic in MKMapView makes the class much, much easier to use. And since MKMapView isn't *managing* the annotations, there's no violation of MVC.